# Magento observer doesnt respond to customer_logout

Tags: magento

I am using Magento `1.7.0.2` (old but this isn't a post about telling me to upgrade please, its not practical right now).

I have an observer which works as expected for every event I am interested in however for some reason attempting to respond to `customer_logout` doesn't work.

I have the following set up:

```
    <!--LOGOUT (doesnt)-->

<customer_logout>
    <observers>
        <analytics_logout>
        <class>analytics/observer</class>
        <method>logCustomerLogout</method>
        <type>singleton</type>  
        </analytics_logout>
    </observers>
</customer_logout>

    <!--LOGIN (Works)-->

<customer_login>
    <observers>
        <analytics_login>
        <class>analytics/observer</class>
        <method>logCustomerLogin</method>
        <type>singleton</type>  
        </analytics_login>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
```

Where the `logCustomerLogout` function is:

```
 public function logCustomerLogout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {


        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('someTagType', 'CustomerLogout');

    }
```

I added logging to `app/Mage.php` to log to the console each event on `DispatchEvent` and the console shows the event is coming through as `customer_logout` so I don't understand what is going on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have logged the output, it does fire. The only logical conclusion would be that some other event that is listening to it prevents it from reaching yours. I would suggest to find those events and log their call - see what is the last one it calls and obviously that is where it stops.